# Как реализовать выборку части текста из сообщения?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть условное приложение, которое позволяет записывать в БД сообщения с секретными кодами внутри. Секретный код записывается внутри фигурных скобок. Надо реализовать такой функционал, чтобы в БД записывалось само сообщение и из него в отдельный столбец выделялись секретные коды (т.е. текст из фигурных скобок). Каким образом можно реализовать данный функционал без использования функций preg_*(), ereg*(), split(), explode() (задание не подразумевает их использование) ?
Пример:
lala-}blab{la ! =))
:(
{457}7775 
32
{98}
соответственно 457 и 98 являются кодами.

Comment: Хоть бы потрудились и пример сообщения с секретными кодами показали.

Comment: в чем суть задания? работать со строками без использования функций для роботы со строками? зачем?

Comment: @Arendach таково ТЗ...

Comment: Поскольку формально количество таких кодов в поле не имеет ограничения, задача при версии MySQL 5+ решается только в формате хранимой процедуры. В версии 8+ можно использовать рекурсивные CTE. *без использования функций preg_(), ereg(), split(), explode() (задание не подразумевает их использование)* По какой причине?